# Disabling "Restore Windows" message in Lion

Tags: osx-lion, messagebox, error-suppression

We have a process that scans 3rd party plug-ins in the background.
It seems that Lion is popping this "The Application X unexpectedly quit while.."
every time the process crashes.

How can we suppress this messages?

Thanks

Comment: i dont want to sound incredibly sarcastic but... write better error handling routines? that window is a service to the user as a matter of convenience. taking it away may not gain you any fans.

Comment: While scanning, it's not our code that causes the exception, it's the 3rd party plugins (bundle) that we're loading, so we can't do much about it..